# in thymeleaf, how to group by a duplicate item?

Tags: thymeleaf

I try to display datas from a list in an html page by grouping by `productType`

Her is my code :

**Models:**

```
public enum ProductType {

HOTEL_PRODUCT("HOTEL_PRODUCT", "Hotel - Product"), 
HEBERG_PRODUCT("HEBERG_PRODUCT", "Lodging - Product");

private final String code;
private final String description;

private ProductType(String code, String description) {
    this.code = code;
    this.description = description;
}

//Getters and Setters....
```

.

```
public class PriceProduct {

private BigDecimal price;
private BigDecimal taxes;

public PriceProduct() {
    super();
}

public PriceProduct(BigDecimal price, BigDecimal taxes) {
    super();
    this.price = price;
    this.taxes = taxes;
}
// Getters and Setters ....
```

.

```
public class Product {

private String productName;
private ProductType productType;
private PriceProduct priceProduct;

public Product() {
    super();
}

public Product(String productName, ProductType productType, PriceProduct priceProduct) {
    super();
    this.productName = productName;
    this.productType = productType;
    this.priceProduct = priceProduct;
} // Getters and Setters
```

.
In the controller i methode:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Product> findAll(Model model){
    List<Product> products=new ArrayList<>();
    products.add(new Product("HAMILTON", ProductType.HOTEL_PRODUCT, new PriceProduct(new BigDecimal(200), new BigDecimal(20)) ));
    products.add(new Product("SWANZI", ProductType.HEBERG_PRODUCT, new PriceProduct(new BigDecimal(100), new BigDecimal(10)) ));        
    products.add(new Product("PAPILLION", ProductType.HOTEL_PRODUCT, new PriceProduct(new BigDecimal(350), new BigDecimal(70)) ));
    products.add(new Product("FORKAT", ProductType.HEBERG_PRODUCT, new PriceProduct(new BigDecimal(399), new BigDecimal(65)) ));        
    model.addAttribute("products", products);
    return products;
}
```

This is my html page:

```
<div th:each="prod,row : ${products}" th:object="${prod}" style="width: 600px;" class="container">
        <div class="col-xs-12" th:text="*{productType.description}"></div>          
        <div class="col-xs-12"></div>           
        <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3" th:text="*{productName}"></div>           
        <div class="col-xs-3" >Price</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3" >Taxes</div>          
        <div class="col-xs-12"></div>           
        <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3" ></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3" th:text="*{priceProduct.price}"></div>            
        <div class="col-xs-3" th:text="*{priceProduct.taxes}"></div>
    </div>
```

But when i display all that it duplicate the productType:

[image]

I am looking for some think like this  :

[image]

Comment: I see no duplicates here

Comment: @Antoniossss I update the post, you can see the duplicate data, so as i said in the question , i would like to group by productType

Comment: How woult you do that in plain Java? You would group items by some categories and use 2 for loops to interate over every category, and every item in that category. Do the same in html template - 2x  for loop.

Comment: @Antoniossss i try to khnow if i can do that via thymeleaf without changing the backend (java)

Comment: You coud, but why would yo make your life harder? Do grouping on backend, use frontend to display the results - that is what MVC is about btw. All in all you will have to do this by yourself either on backedn (easy, natural way) or via some SpEL expressions on frontend (hard, masohistic way)

Comment: @Antoniossss now it's a project of the compagny and what i am trying to display is in fragment page and the list witch i try to iterate comes from the parrent page via the include tag , it impossible to change to make any change in  java side :(

Comment: You will have to use SpEL - or change frontend to be middleware - like angular (simply speaking, its backend on frontend ;):) Dont count on me to provide solution as it is not straightforward nor simple IMHO. I wont bother to try to implement it - my advice for you is to do the same.

Comment: @Antoniossss Ops! It's basicly a spring boot + thymeleaf project

Comment: I got that in first place :) Not everything can be done in `V` layer using thymeleaf. Thats not `JSP` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution bellow but if you can propose an other one more simple, so do it :)

```
<div th:each="prod,row : ${products.?[productType == T(com.test.model.ProductType).HOTEL_PRODUCT]}" th:object="${prod}"  style="width: 600px;" class="container" >

            <div class="col-xs-12" th:text="*{productType.description}" th:if="${row.first}"></div>

            <div class="col-xs-12"></div>

            <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3" th:text="*{productName}"></div>           
            <div class="col-xs-3" >Price</div>
            <div class="col-xs-3" >Taxes</div>

            <div class="col-xs-12"></div>

            <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3" ></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3" th:text="*{priceProduct.price}"></div>            
            <div class="col-xs-3" th:text="*{priceProduct.taxes}"></div>
    </div>
    <div th:each="prod,row : ${products.?[productType == T(com.test.model.ProductType).HEBERG_PRODUCT]}" th:object="${prod}"  style="width: 600px;" class="container" >
            <div class="col-xs-12" th:text="*{productType.description}"  th:if="${row.first}"></div>

            <div class="col-xs-12"></div>

            <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3" th:text="*{productName}"></div>           
            <div class="col-xs-3" >Price</div>
            <div class="col-xs-3" >Taxes</div>

            <div class="col-xs-12"></div>

            <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3" ></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3" th:text="*{priceProduct.price}"></div>            
            <div class="col-xs-3" th:text="*{priceProduct.taxes}"></div>
    </div>
```